Why not use the anomaly datasets to train an autoencoder?
When using autoencoders for detecting network anomalies, why not train them using anomaly datasets? Reconstruction errors smaller than a threshold could signify anomalies, while those larger than the threshold could represent normal data. Can this method be effective? But why do most people choose to train autoencoders using regular datasets?
I want to utilize an autoencoder trained on anomaly data for network intrusion detection. I want to know its feasibility.
